# extract the predicted values from caret machine learning models in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I'm new to stackoverflow so I apologize in advance for any mistakes I make.

I'm running various machine learning models in R using the **caret** package- **Logistic Regression, SVM, Decision tree, Boosted tree, Neural Network and K- Nearest Neighbors**.

I use caret as implementing all these models is just a matter of changing the name of the method.

I want to extract the predicitons made by the model on both the training and the test set with the idea that these predicitions for the output/dependent variable will be stored back to the dataset for comparison with the actual values.

I researched and was able to find the code below:

`results<-extractPrediction(models, testX = NULL, testY = NULL, unkX = NULL, unkOnly = !is.null(unkX) & is.null(testX), verbose = FALSE)`

where models is a list of all the models whose result is to be extracted.

Firstly, the code threw an error unless executed in the following manner, but let's leave that for the moment.

`results<-extractPrediction(models)`

Now, when I feed in the models into this function, I do get the actual and predicted values for the model, but since there is no index number available, I don't know which value corresponds to which record in the original dataset.

Secondly, the models being fed into the function contain only the training set and not the test set. I need to pull predicted values for both the training and test set combined and in the correct order for comparison.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible or am I simply shooting for the stars??

I'm also including a sample of the models I'm using for your reference:

### Implementing Linear SVM on the dataset

```
    cl <- parallel::makeCluster(detectCores(logical=TRUE), type='PSOCK')
    doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

   start.time <- Sys.time()
   trnControl <- trainControl(method='cv',number=5, allowParallel = T,verboseIter = T) 

   set.seed(11)
   ds1lnrsvm <- train(shortflag~., data=trnds1,method="svmLinear",
                   trControl=trnControl)
   ds1lnrsvm_t<- Sys.time() - start.time

   parallel::stopCluster(cl)
   registerDoSEQ()


## Implementing Linear SVM model on test dataset
   ds1lnrsvmres <- predict(object=ds1lnrsvm, newdata=testds1) 

## confusion matrix to check performance
   confusionMatrix(data=ds1lnrsvmres, reference=testds1$shortflag,positive="1")
```

Any help or suggestions as to how to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just based on what you've described so far, it everything should be possible in `caret`.

My approach to this problem would be to use the `lappy` function over a list of all of the model types you want to estimate.  The nice thing about this is that when you are done, you will have all of the `train` objects neatly grouped together, which you can name, and then easily extract whatever information you are looking for.

Now that you have this nice list, you can just iterate through them again with another apply function to create the resepective `confusionMatrix` objects, which you can either save as a list, or just extract, directly, whatever information you are after, with respects to predictions or accuracy on the testing set.

From there, it should be pretty easy to bind the information you extract into tables to print, compare, plot, etc.

So, for example:

```
# set model names
models <- c("plr", "svmLinear", "rpart", "ada", "nnet", "knn")  

# set train control params
trnControl <- trainControl(method='cv',number=5, allowParallel = T,verboseIter = T) 

# fit models
set.seed(11)

train_models <- lapply(models, function(model){ 
    print(model)
    train(shortflag ~ ., method = model, data = trnds1, trControl = trnControl) 
}) 

# name the models in your list
names(train_models) <- models
```

With that, you have a nice list.  If you do `View(train_models)`, you can click through and expand all of the different lists and see what are the things that you can extract within them. So for example, you could do something like this, to get the training accuracy, which returns a named list so you know what is what:

```
# extract training accuracy
elapsed <- sapply(train_models, function(object) 
    object$results["Accuracy"])
```

Next, with your list of trained models, it's relatively simple to go through and create the `confusionMatrix` to get to whatever information you are after with the testing data. Here is an example of directly extracting a list of model accuracy from test set:

```
# extract test accuracy
test_accuracy = sapply(train_models, function(x){
    pred = predict(x, newdata = testds1)
    cm = confusionMatrix(pred, reference = testds1$shortflag)
    return(cm[["overall"]]["Accuracy"])
```

One word of advice: if you decide to try this method, I would first take a small subset of your training and testing data, and try getting the code to work exactly as you want it on that small subset first, before you start using all your data, as once you feed the entire list of models into the `lapply` function as described in the first step above, it could take quite a while to get through.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: to add, there is a great function `resamples(train_models)` in `caret` to produce a nice output as in `parallelplot(resamples(train_models), metric = "RMSE")` or just `summary(resamples(train_models)`

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem without `trnds1`/`testds1,` but maybe below is what you want.

```
library(dplyr)

pred <- extractPrediction(list(NAME = ds1lnrsvm),   # extractPrediction want list(model)
                          testX = select(testds1, -shortflag),
                          testY = pull(testds1, shortflag))

trnds1 %>%                  # train data 
  bind_rows(testds1) %>%    # bind_rows with testdata
  bind_cols(pred) # %>%     # add cols of predict
  # select(-shortflag) # shortflg is the same as obs, if you want please delete the col.
```

Comment: cuttlefish44 you gave me just what I needed.  Thank you!,